# Problems with JQuery Galleria and IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, galleria

I have a problem that I can't figure out what to do next. I have a website using JQuery Galleeria in an HTML page and 10 pictures autoplay scrolling  at the top of the page. It is using the Classic theme and is very basic functionality.

I tested it on my local IIS server and on an internal build server in IE7, Chrome, Opera, Firefox and it worked fine. I published it on a live server and it intermittently broke in IE7. It does a few strange things:

1. It blows up the picture bigger than the original, even though I put "max_scale_ratio: 1" in my JS.
2. It adds forward and back arrows next to my thumbnails that aren't there for any other browser.
3. It stops showing the thumbnails after the first picture.

All of this is intermittent and if I refresh the page several times it can correct itself or sometimes does the above.

My JS code on the page is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Load theme
    Galleria.loadTheme('themes/classic/galleria.classic.js');

    // run galleria and add some options
    $('#galleria').galleria({
        debug: true,
        image_crop: true,
        height: 397,
        max_scale_ratio: 1, //Ensures the picture crop doesn't zoom the picture
        autoplay: 8000, //Sets an autoplay interval of 8 seconds (8000)
        transition: 'fade',
        data_config: function(img) {
            return {
                description: $(img).next('p').html()
            };
        }
    });
```

I have no idea why it is just breaking on the live server and working on the others. I can't find any source of help that shows the same problem. Is it a server problem or something I can fix in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a bug with Galleria (as referenced by a Galleria support person to me) and they are addressing. It is an IE7 issue. The suggested solution is to use a JSON array instead of calling to the pictures directly until the bug is fixed.